# Is loggin in from 2 different light wallets at the same time possible?

Tags: seed, light-node

Is it possible to log into my seed from one computer (light node) and at the same time log in from another computer or from android wallet?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. 
Iota is a decentralized protocol. There is no central server managing any kind of session.

When you execute a transaction on one client, you do the pow to attach it to the tangle (it usually take a few seconds). Once the transaction is attached : the transaction is now a tip and is broadcasted on the network. 
The transaction will be visible in other client very soon (delay mainly depends of the network topology)

Comment: And what happens if I do a transaction on one computer? When do I see it on the second computer?

Comment: @vrom see my edit